# EXC_BAD_ACCESS when trying to use TOSMBClient to upload file using SMB1

Tags: ios, swift, smb

I'm trying to use TOSMBClient to upload a file using SMB1.

When I try to upload the file I'm getting the following error `Thread 4: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x50)`

It is occuring at the following part of the library:

```
dispatch_sync(self.session.serialQueue, ^{
```

Here is the code that I'm using to initiate the upload:

```
    let session = TOSMBSession.init(ipAddress: serverURL);
    session?.setLoginCredentialsWithUserName(username, password: password);

    let path = "I_AM_A_FILE.txt";
    let data = path.data(using: .utf8)

    self.uploadTask = session!.uploadTaskForFile(atPath: path, data: data as Data?, progressHandler: nil, completionHandler: {
        print("send")
    }) { (error) in
        print("got error == ", error as Any)
    }
    self.uploadTask?.resume();
```

Thanks very much

Comment: Could you also add the output from the debug output window? Are you sure that `session!` does not crash because it's nil?

Comment: Hey @AndreasOetjen ye it looks like session is nil when `dispatch_sync(self.session.serialQueue, ^{` is called. it's definately not nil when I'm first calling the upload method though, any idea why?

Comment: You seem to have two variables `session` -- one is local (`let session = TOSMBSession`), the other a property of your type (`self.session`). Is this intended?

Comment: Ye, the `dispatch_sync(self.session.serialQueue, ^{` is part of the TOSMBClient library. It is called when I use `session.uploadTaskForFile`

Comment: Did you try to run your program with address or thread sanitizer enabled? (In the scheme editor -> Run -> Diagnostics)?